# Calling a ptototype function

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

I am working with a piece of code that I found in another project on the net and I am trying to adapt it to my needs. I wasn't able to find out how this function was originally being called so I am hoping to find some assistance here.

```
var gatewayIP = '192.168.10.21',
sock = new WebSocket('ws://' + gatewayIP + ':8000');
sock.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

// Constructor, expects a socket/stream to write device commands 
function HTDLync(sock, log) {
    this.sock = sock;
    this.log = log;
}

// Change zone power state ('On', 'Off', '1', or '0')
HTDLync.prototype.setPower = function(zone, power) {

    powerStr = power.toString().toLowerCase();

    var packet = Buffer.from([0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x58]);
    packet.writeUInt8(this.cleanZone(zone), 2);

    if (powerStr == 'on' || powerStr == '1'){
        packet.writeUInt8(0x57, 4);
    }
    else if (powerStr == 'off' || powerStr == '0'){
        packet.writeUInt8(0x58, 4);
    }
    else {
        this.log.warn('Unknown setPower argument:', powerStr);
        return;
    }

    var dataOut = addChecksum(packet);
    this.log.debug('Sending setPower command:', dataOut.toString('hex'));
    msg.payload = dataOut;
};
```

I have tried calling the following:

```
setPower('1', 'On');
this.setPower('1', 'On');
HTDLync.setPower('1', 'On');
```

All of the above hit the console with function not defined errors.

I feel like I am either missing some other code or calling this function incorrectly.

How would I go about calling this `setPower` prototype function ?

Comment: to "access" `HTDLync.prototype.setPower` you would (usually) need an object that is the result of `new HTDLync()` - e.g. `var x = new HTDLync(blah, blha); x.setPower(whatever, blah);`

Answer (score 0):

To call a (prototype) method, you need to make an *instance* of the class first by calling the constructor:

```
var obj = new HTDLync(new WebSocket('ws://192.168.10.21:8000'), console);
```

Only then you can invoke the method on that object:

```
obj.setPower('1', 'On');
```

Have a look at MDN's introduction to [OOP in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) and [usage of prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

Answer (score 0):

You must `new HTDLync` first to use!

```
var htdLync = new HTDLync();
htdLync.setPower('1', 'On');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: the argument is not mandatory to pass but as you have mentioned in constructor so you pass it.

```
var obj= new HTDLync(agr1,arg2); 
obj.setPower('1', 'On');
```